# How to efficiently swap values between two instances of same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two `Book` instances where I want to swap `sequence` column values between two `books`

```
## Original values
# book_1.sequence = 10  
# book_2.sequence = 15

book_id = [1,2]

book_1 = Book.find(book_id.first)
book_2 = Book.find(book_id.second)

book_1_sequence = book_1.sequence
book_2_sequence = book_2.sequence

book_1.update_attributes!(sequence: book_2_sequence)
book_2.update_attributes!(sequence: book_1_sequence)
```

After program execution :

`book_1.sequence = 15`
            `book_2.sequence = 10`

This does the trick, but this is pretty straightforward, is there any better way to do it? neater and efficient

Comment: Define "efficient".

Comment: Tip: you likely didn't think about it, but you should make this whole operation atomic (by wrapping it in a db transaction or something like that). Otherwise, it's very prone to corruption/race condition (if there are several concurrent reorderings going on).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Will include it in a `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way of doing this:

```
# Original values
book_1.sequence
 => 10

book_2.sequence
 => 15

book_ids = [1,2]

# Fetch all the books in single query
book_1, book_2 = Book.find(book_ids)

book_1.sequence, book_2.sequence = book_2.sequence, book_1.sequence
[book_1, book_2].each(&:save!)
```

Answer (score 0):

At least one line of code can be reduced:

```
book_1.sequence = 10  
book_2.sequence = 15

book_id = [1,2]

book_1, book_2 = Book.find(book_ids)

book_1_sequence = book_1.sequence

book_1.update_attributes!(sequence: book_2.sequence)
book_2.update_attributes!(sequence: book_1_sequence)
```

Updated with Robbert van ELk suggestion.

Comment: Nice, can we do `book_1.sequence , book_2.sequence =  book_2.sequence , book_1.sequence`
and call book_1.save! && book_2.save!

Comment: Yes, but only if this column is not unique in the table.

Comment: Maybe just do one database call Book.find(book_ids) instead of calling Book.find twice

Comment: Thanks for the solution, What you meant by `if this column is not unique in the table.` @PavelOganesyan

Comment: @dextermorgan Let's suppose that we have something like `  add_index :books, :sequence, unique: true` in a migration. After that both provided versions of swap that will fail with exception.

Answer (score 0):

Swap in a single line with ruby

```
# Original values
# book_1.sequence = 10  
# book_2.sequence = 15

book_id = [1,2]

book_1, book_2 = Book.find(book_ids)

book_1.sequence, book_2.sequence = book_2.sequence, book_1.sequence
book_1.save; book_2.save
```

Even shorter (**not recommended**, since it's very confusing, definitely not neat and unintuitive):

```
Book.find(book_ids).tap { |book_1, book_2| book_1.sequence, book_2.sequence = book_2.sequence, book_1.sequence }.map &:save
```

`#tap` *yields* the self in block, which maps to `book_1` and `book_2`, swaps the sequence values and returns back the *books* in same order, which `save` then saves it.

Comment: I wouldn't do this in your "even shorter" one line way... That's very confusing!

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to show that shorter version is available. added a note :)